# What is the difference? Dedicated Server Hosting/Cloud Hosting

Tags: webserver, cloud-computing

I want to know which is more cost effective and powerful for hosting games and apps. As I understand it, a game console is powerful because it is a dedicated machine. On the other hand, I hear cloud servers run on clustering. Both of these methods are expensive and have their differences. Outline them please.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote is because of the mention of game/app hosting, or perhaps its because of the wording of my question?

Comment: What does hosting a game server have to do with a game console exactly?  Many of your questions can be answered by doing simple research.  A game console makes a horrible server equipment.

Comment: I was using a game console as an example of a dedicated machine to further illustrate my question.

Comment: I think I was clear. I want an answer to a direct question, as well as an outline of the reasons for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dedicated servers are physical machines, fully dedicated to high-performance hardware to accommodate high requests.

The resources of a dedicated server are usually used below `60%`, so it never runs at full capacity. A fully loaded cloud can save a lot of electricity and money since it can replace 5 times of the dedicated servers.

The Cloud Computing is a slice of a set of features available in dozens of servers and storage, enabling scalability, availability and performance assurance environment.

**Cost difference**

Monthly cost for dedicated servers may range from `$100` to `$1,000` depending upon the packages.

In case of cloud computing, it basically is about how much you use. 
You only get charged for the amount of storage and the time for which you use the storage.  The best part about cloud storage is that there is nothing that is capped like dedicated servers.

Whether it is data store cost or data transfer cost, a user is charged only for what he uses on the cloud.

Comment: What about the negative sides of cloud hosting such as being locked into whatever OS and / or "platform" that is offered by the provider?

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин how are you not "locked into whatever OS and / or platform" if you use a dedicated server? Unless you are talking about high end professional servers, in which case you are administering it yourself, you will still need to use whatever system your hosting service provides.

Comment: @terdon I'm assuming that the provider allows you to choose what to run on a dedicated server.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин OK, never heard of that. I've seen a few that offer both Windows and Linux but none that lets you actually _choose_ which OS to install. I'd love to be able to choose the Linux that my server runs for example but I've never seen a service that offers that. I'm pretty sure that if you want that level of choice, you'll need to set it up yourself.

Comment: @terdon alright, good comment. But I was wondering if there are also other negative sides to a "cloud hosting" solution.

Comment: @terdon: Many hosting providers give you access to the BIOS and let you do the whole server setup yourself if you want to -- all remotely.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz really? Cool, I'll keep that in mind next time I go looking. Mind you when I do, it tends to be in the "small business" scale so I probably won't find (or need) that at my price range. Good to know though, thanks.